# MenuItem.NavigateUrl appending to URL instead of redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspmenu

Here is my c#;

```
string myUrl = "www.facebook.com"
menuItem1.NavigateUrl = myUrl;
```

here is my markup

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu" runat="server">
</asp:menu>
```

But when I click the menu item, it appends to the url and does not redirect

I get ;

```
http://domain.com#http://domain.com/www.facebook.com
```

When I expect it to just redirect.  Can anyone point out my , maybe obvious mistake?

Comment: `Here's is my markup`  That is c# code, not markup.  Post the real markup.

Comment: Try by specifying the protocol in myUrl variable. "http:// whatever"

Comment: @Partha gave me the same result

Comment: I quickly tried your requirement with an existing project I have. And it worked fine for me. I used the following syntax: string url = "http://www.facebook.com";
Menu1.Items[0].NavigateUrl = url;
Btw, what is menuItem1 ? what property is it ?

Comment: Actually it is http:// and then url in my answer, changes automatically

Comment: @Partha I figured out its javascript on my ASP page causing this.  Thank you for your contribution though good sir!

Comment: Oh okay. But does it work without http:// ?

Comment: @Partha yes, but only because I removed javascript